# Tooltip is shown under popup window

Tags: bug, design, tooltips

I was looking at edit with added tags and wanted to see tag description (in tooltip), but unfortunately tooltip was shown under the popup:

[image]

Chrome, Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: The z-index strikes again ...